# Access JSTL tag from code inside of forEach loop

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Is it possible to access JSTL's forEach variable via code from within the loop?

```
<c:forEach items="${elements}" var="element">
    <% element.someMethod(); %>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I believe "element" is stored in the page context.

```
<c:forEach items="${elements}" var="element">
    <% ((Element) pageContext.getAttribute("elements")).someMethod(); %>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity, where'd you find this method of access?

Comment: I've put things in session and request contexts many times for use in a JSP. Plus I knew that the page context is like them.

Comment: minor fix: pageContext.getAttribute("element") instead of pageContext.getAttribute("elements")

Answer (score -1):

Edit following the correction of the example:

Yes, it is possible to access the `var` inside the `c:forEach`

Here's an example:

```
<c:forEach items="${elements}" var="element">
    ${((Element)element).someMethod()}
</c:forEach>
```

See [c:forEach](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) in the JSTL Documentation.